# Regarding the construction of 犯罪

Tags: words, kanji

I was playing with Kanji Kentei exercises. The area: 熟語の構成.

> The word in question: 犯罪
>
> The correct answer: 下の文字が上の文字の目的語・補語になっているもの（着席）

Makes sense: 罪を犯す → 犯罪

---

Now the question: what makes it not fit the category 同じような意味の漢字を重ねたもの（岩石）?

I find the two characters meeting the criteria for 同じような意味:

罪＝法にふれる。
犯＝しきりをふみこえる。法やおきてをやぶる。

Do these categories have an order like "first matched A so A")? Or are there some other criteria?

Comment: Why do you think it can fit into that category?

Comment: Because both characters are synonymously used as components meaning "crime". 犯人 and 罪人 as the most basic example.

Comment: Where did you find the definition of 罪? It should be a noun rather than a verb.

Comment: @broccoliforest For the purpose of answering the first comment I googled for 罪とは. I'm also not sure how a single character can be considered a noun or a verb and what are the implications for the above case. Maybe the answer should address this concern too. If anything, I would assume both characters 犯, 罪 are "nouns" as 石 and 岩 are.

Comment: @macraf Yup there's actually a lot in Chinese "word class" problem, but anyway I don't recommend believing too much what Google suggests on the top of the page for the time being...

Comment: @macraf Writing a (decent) answer takes time, please be patient :)

Comment: @broccoliforest Nothing in my thinking assumes either of the characters represents a verb, or a noun, or any other part of speech. I find both characters having similar meaning and fitting into the category I asked about. I got a comment, so I checked once again. The definitions seem synonymous, whichever of them I looked at. To make my response more substantial I quoted the first definition found, because I don't see a need to be picky. You asked what resource I quoted, so I answered. Again, nothing in my reasoning is based on the result of googling.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, 罪 and 犯 never make synonyms. Despite loose notion of word class in Chinese grammar, people usually know a word's semantic category e.g. is an object, quality, action etc.

罪 is usually considered an abstract entity: a *crime*, *sin*, or *guilt* etc. 犯 represents action: *violate*, *trespass*, *infringe* etc. Doesn't 犯 also mean "infringement"? Yes, but it's only "action of infringing" and not "infringed state". In other words, 犯 could mean "crime-committing" but not "crime".

You could argue that 犯人 "committer" and 罪人 "criminal" are synonyms, but not for "commit" and "crime".

> Do these categories have an order like "first matched A so A")? Or are there some other criteria?

There is unfortunately no rule to deduce what construction a word has. You can guess from kanji meaning, but its mostly lexical so that you have to memorize one by one if you seek accuracy; for example, 作曲 "music composition" is verb-object ("make music") type, but 作品 "art work" is adjective-noun ("made goods").

Comment: I think the latter part, with the 作 example, is quite revealing. However, what category does 犯行 fall into? If it's also 目的語・補語 then I don't understand the claim of "never" in the first part.

Comment: @macraf Usually we use in meaning "violating act", so, adjective-noun?

Comment: @macraf Oh, such interpretation never came to my mind. In my impression, the 行 "deed" itself is hard to 犯 "violate" in my impression. (Of course you can't "violate" crimes in English, but it's a lexical matter that you can agree with object when you do "wrongdoing".)

Comment: No, I don't get the first part of the answer. Drawing an analogy from the 作 example: the structure and function of individual components is related to (determined by?) the meaning of the composite expression. You can 作品を作る, but you cannot 作曲を作る, right? Why then 犯罪を犯す is ok? It looks even as (if not "同じような") 犯罪 fits into adjective-noun pattern.

Comment: @macraf That's an exceptionally good point. Actually 犯罪を犯す is a frequently criticized piece of bad grammar (the prescriptive wording is 罪を犯す), but people keep using it, because 犯罪 has almost taken over the position of most basic word for "crime" as 罪 is becoming loftier. So you can say 犯罪 now mean "crime" as a whole, irrelevant to its etymological construction.

Answer (score 1):

> 罪＝法にふれる。

罪 is a noun. Therefore, this explanation is not accurate.

> 罪＝法にふれる**行為**、法にふれる**事**

This is more accurate.

> 犯＝しきりをふみこえる。法やおきてをやぶる。

This explanation is correct. 犯す is a verb.

In case of 岩石, 岩 and 石 are both nouns. Therefore the two words have the near-the-same meaning and the same 品詞.

As you said, 罪 and 犯 may have the resembling meaning, however, according to the 品詞の違い, the interpretation, 罪を犯す, seems much easier to understand.

Does this explanation make sense to you?

同じような意味 should include the premise that they are the 同じ品詞.